# How to get the new standard deviation?

Tags: normal-distribution

I have this statement:

> A continuous random var $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ where $\mu = 1.5, \sigma^2 = 0.1$
>
> If $\mu$ increase in $20\%$, what is the new standard deviation?

My attempt was:

When the $\mu$ is multiply by some constant $k$, in this case $1.2$ means that:

$\mu\cdot k=k\cdot p(X=x_1)\cdot x_1+...+k\cdot P(X =x_n)\cdot x_n$

$\mu \cdot k =k[ p(X=x_1)\cdot x_1+...+ P(X =x_n) \cdot x_n]$

So, we are multiplying all the data by a factor $k$, and and using the property of:

If you multiply all the data by a constant $c$, the new standard deviation will be $\sigma \cdot c$, and the variance $\sigma^2 \cdot c^2$.

Thus, the new standard deviations is equal to $\sqrt{0.1}\cdot 1.2$

But the correct answer must be $1.2^2 \cdot 0.1$. So, what is wrong with my development?

Comment: That is the variance!

Comment: So, i am right?

Comment: Well,I would do the same if I were you...

Comment: But note that as this is a continuous distribution $P(X=x)=0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: So...? how to get the correct answer?

Comment: I would consider the random variable $Y=1.2X$ and then find $Var(Y)$

Comment: $Var(1.2X) = 1.2^2 \cdot V(X)$ , but it's still my same answer

Comment: If u can, please provide me an answer to how get the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$X \sim N(1.5,0.1)$$

You wrote $\mu$ increased in $20\%$ ,i.e, new mean is $1.5×1.2=1.8$
Let us consider another random variable $Y=1.2X$ .
Note that $\mathbb{E}(Y)=1.8$
And $\mathbb{Var}(Y)=\mathbb{Var}(1.2X)=1.2^2\mathbb{Var}(X)=1.2^2×0.1$